# How to combination/permutation in ruby?

Tags: ruby

I've this familiar question that looks like permutation/combination of the Math world.

How can I achieve the following via ruby?

```
badges = "1-2-3"

badge_cascade = []
badges.split("-").each do |b|
  badge_cascade << b
end

Gives: => ["1", "2", "3"]

But I want it to be is:

=> ["1", "2", "3", 
  "1-2", "2-3", "3-1", "2-1", "3-2", "1-3", 
  "1-2-3", "2-3-1", "3-1-2"]
```

Comment: the expected values for permutations of 3 elements look weird, only 3 elements? I count 6.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Functional approach:

```
bs = "1-2-3".split("-")
strings = 1.upto(bs.size).flat_map do |n| 
  bs.permutation(n).map { |vs| vs.join("-") } 
end
#=> ["1", "2", "3", "1-2", "1-3", "2-1", "2-3", "3-1", "3-2", "1-2-3", "1-3-2", "2-1-3", "2-3-1", "3-1-2", "3-2-1"]
```

Answer (score 5):

You ned to use [Array#permutation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-permutation) method in order to get all permutations:

```
arr = "1-2-3".split '-' # => ["1", "2", "3"]
res = (1..arr.length).reduce([]) { |res, length|
  res += arr.permutation(length).to_a
}.map {|arr| arr.join('-')}

puts res.inspect
# => ["1", "2", "3", "1-2", "1-3", "2-1", "2-3", "3-1", "3-2", "1-2-3", "1-3-2", "2-1-3", "2-3-1", "3-1-2", "3-2-1"]
```

Let me explain the code:

1. You split string into array passing separator `'-'` to [String#split](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-split) method
2. You need all permutations of length 1, 2, 3. Range `1..arr.length` represents all these lengths.
3. You collect an array of all permutations using [Enumerable#reduce](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-reduce).
   You will get array of arrays here:

   ```
   [["1"], ["2"], ["3"], ["1", "2"], ["1", "3"], ["2", "1"], ["2", "3"], ["3", "1"], ["3", "2"], ["1", "2", "3"], ["1", "3", "2"], ["2", "1", "3"], ["2", "3", "1"], ["3", "1", "2"], ["3", "2", "1"]]
   ```
4. You transform all subarrays of this array into strings using [Array#join](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-join) with your `'-'` separator inside of [Enumerable#map](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-map)

Comment: note that you are emulating the existing abstraction `flat_map` with `reduce`+`concat`.

Answer (score 2):

`Array#permutation(n)` will give you all the permutations of length *n* as an Array of Arrays so you can call this with each length between 1 and the number of digits in *badges*. The final step is to map these all back into strings delimited with `-`.

```
badges = "1-2-3"

badges_split = badges.split('-')

permutations = []

(1..badges_split.size).each do |n|
    permutations += badges_split.permutation(n).to_a
end

result = permutations.map { |permutation| permutation.join('-') }
```

---

**Update:** *I think Alex's use of `reduce` is a more elegant approach but I'll leave this answer here for now in case it is useful.*