# Creating combination from a multi-dimensional array in Ruby

Tags: ruby

Here is my problem:

Given a multi dimensional array: `[['monday', 'saturday'], ['beginner'], ['kid', 'adult']]`

I want:

```
['monday', 'monday-beginner', 'monday-beginner-kid', 'monday-beginner-adult', 'monday-kid', 'monday-adult', 
 'saturday', 'saturday-beginner', 'saturday-beginner-kid', 'saturday-beginner-adult', 'saturday-kid', 'saturday-adult', 
 'beginner', 'beginner-kid', 'beginner-adult',
 'kid',
 'adult']
```

Here are questions I saw that could help:

- [Creating permutations from a multi-dimensional array in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5582481/creating-permutations-from-a-multi-dimensional-array-in-ruby)
- [How to combination/permutation in ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9019007/how-to-combination-permutation-in-ruby)

Comment: The rule is not clear.

Comment: Why don't you want e.g. `'monday-kid'` or `'saturday-adult'`? In total you are missing 4 obvious combinations

Comment: And the trivial `''`.

Comment: And how is permutation relevant here? It only looks like a combination problem.

Comment: My bad, I also want 'monday-kid' and 'saturday-adult'

Comment: To clarify sawa's commemt, a permutation might be `'kid-monday-beginner'`. The difference is important for clarity, although that might be one of your sticking points of course - if you are not clear yourself on the difference between those terms, it is harder to approach the code correctly.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Actually that's because I wasn't sure the difficulty of having what I'd like to have and having everything permuted too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
first, *rest = [['monday', 'saturday'], ['beginner'], ['kid', 'adult']]
.map{|a| [nil, *a]}
first.product(*rest).map{|a| a.compact.join("-")} - [""]
```

Comment: Nice idea with mixed-in `nil` ;)

Answer (score 0):

I've a solution in 2 steps :
- Find all the possible combinaisons, 4 in your examples:

```
['monday', 'beginner', 'kid']
['monday', 'beginner', 'adult']
['saturday', 'beginner', 'kid']
['saturday', 'beginner', 'adult']
```

Then use [combinaison](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Array.html#method-i-combination) method on it 3 times using n from 1 to 3 and then, merge the 3 returns. You'll finally just have to call .join("-") on each permutation.