# Matching groups of words

Tags: ruby, regex

I would like a regexp that match all groups of words (single words and sub-sentences) in a sentence separated by white space.

Example :

```
"foo bar bar2".scan(regexp)
```

I want a `regexp` that will returns :

```
['foo', 'bar', 'bar2', 'foo bar', 'bar bar2', 'foo bar bar2']
```

So far, I tried :

`"foo bar bar2".scan(/\S*[\S]/)` (ie `regexp=/\S*/`)
which returns `['foo', 'bar', 'bar2']`

`"foo bar bar2".scan(/\S* [\S]+/)`  (ie `regexp=/\S* [\S]+/`)
which returns `["foo bar", " bar2"]`

Comment: But your desired regex also returns non-groups (single words)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Yes, I want both single words and sub-sentences

Comment: Can't be done with a single regex. Your best bet is to scan for individual words and then combine them into sub-sentences as you wish.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Damn, that was what I was tring to avoid :/ I will do it anyway, thx.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
words = "foo bar bar2".scan(/\S+/)
result = 1.upto(words.length).map do |n|
  words.each_cons(n).to_a
end.flatten(1)
#⇒ [["foo"], ["bar"], ["bar2"],
#   ["foo", "bar"], ["bar", "bar2"],
#   ["foo", "bar", "bar2"]]

result.map { |e| e.join(' ') }
#⇒ ["foo", "bar", "bar2", "foo bar", "bar bar2", "foo bar bar2"]
```

Here we used [`Enumerable#each_cons`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_cons) to get to the result.

Comment: It would be great to provide some code explanation. Code only answers often make others post follow-up questions.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew honestly, I am not sure how this answer may be made better with plain English explanation. The key is `Enumerable#each_cons`, and that’s it.

Comment: Then look [here](https://ideone.com/5K5K3T). The output is not as expected.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew `puts` prints arrays’ content on separate lines, it’s a glitch of `puts`, not that “output is not as expected.”

Comment: Yeah, but this is a kind of question you could avoid if you added a demo and an explanation. Not everyone is aware of `puts` glitches or why this code should work at all.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew you convinced me, thanks, I have updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Mudasobwa did a nice variation of this answer [check here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9019608/7884077).
I've used *combine* , builtin method for arrays. The procedure is almost the same:

```
    string = "foo bar bar2"
    groups = string.split
    objects = []

      for i in 1..groups.size
       groups = string.split.combination(i).to_a
       objects << groups
      end

     results = objects.flatten(1).map { |e| e.join('-') }
     puts results
```

Anyway , you can't do it with one regex.(suppose you have 50 words and need to find all the combinations; regex can't do it). You will need to iterate with the objects like Mudasobwa showed.

I would start doing this: the regex, if you want to use one, can be /([^\s]\w+)/m ; for example.
This regex will match words. And by words I mean groups of characters surrounded by white-spaces.

With this you can scan your text or split your string. You can do it many ways and in the end you will have an array with the words you wanna combine.

```
    string = "foo bar bar2"
```

Then you split it, creating an array and applying to it the combination method.

```
  groups = string.split
    => ["foo", "bar", "bar2"]
```

combination method takes a number as argument, and that number will be the 'size' of the combination. combination(2) combines the elements in groups of two. 1 - groups of 1 .. 0 groups of zero! (this is why we start combinations with 1).

You need to loop and cover all possible group sizes, saving the results
in a results array. :

```
    objects = []
```

use the number of elements as parameter to the loop

```
       for i in 1..groups.size
         groups = string.split.combination(i).to_a
         objects << groups
        end
```

Now you just have to finish with a loop to flatten the arrays that are inside arrays and to take out the comas and double quotes

results = objects.flatten(1).map { |e| e.join('-') }

Thats it! You can run the code above (example with more words)here https://repl.it/JLK9/1

Ps: both question and the mentioned answer are lacking a combination (foo-bar2)

Comment: Thx, there a problem with combination. It will give me all the combinations of words even the words that are not following them selves in the sentence. In my example, I will get "foo bar2" which I don't want.